# get_absolute_url with parameters

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
        ...
        url(r'^profile/$', profile.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

My `model`:

```
class Reg(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_reg', null=True)
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:profile', ???)
```

My `views`:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    context_dict = {}
    u = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    context_dict['user'] = u
    r = reg.Reg.objects.get(user=u)
    context_dict['reg'] = r
    return render(request, 'core/reg.html', context_dict)
```

Is it possible use get_absolute_url to views different profiles? For example from the /admin when you look the profile "John", you click on the "view on site" and obtain the profile page with john datas, not yours

Comment: What would you use to query John's data, id or name? Or may be you could update your question with more fields from your model

Comment: I can use both.... edit: now i'm going to update. Done.

Comment: At the moment neither the URL or the view you've shown us has any provision to view the profile of any user other than the one you're logged in as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your views must be able to accept an extra argument, preferably the user id, since names usually contain spaces:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def profile(request, user_id):
    context_dict = {}
    u = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    context_dict['user'] = u
    r = reg.Reg.objects.get(user=u)
    context_dict['reg'] = r
    return render(request, 'core/reg.html', context_dict)
```

Then your `urls.py` becomes:

```
urlpatterns = [
        ...
        url(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', profile.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

And finally your `models.py` and the `get_absolute_url` method:

```
class Reg(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_reg', null=True)
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:profile', user_id=self.id)
```