# Dynamic get_absolute_url using url query parameters

Tags: django, django-views, url-parameters, modelform, django-generic-views

*Big picture*: I'd like my reverse method in get_absolute_url (see below) to return a url with a query parameter appended to it at the end, e.g. `<url>?foo=bar`.  Further, I'd like `bar` to be specified by the POST request that triggered the call to get_absolute_url, either as an input to the form (but not a field represented by the model, something temporary) or as a url query parameter.  I am easily able to access `bar` in my view using either method, but I can't seem to figure out how to access it in my model.

The motivation here is that my detail page splits up the fields from my model into different tabs using javascript (think https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp).  When the user is updating the model, they choose which tab they want to update, and then the update template only renders the fields from the model which are related  to that tab.  More importantly, after the user submits the update, I want the detail page to know to open the specific tab that the user just edited.

(I understand how this works if the field is a part of the model; in [get_absolute_url with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378437/get-absolute-url-with-parameters), the solution is pretty straightforward and involves using `self.id`.  In my case though, `bar` is not a part of the model and I can't figure out how else to access it)

*Some specifics*: I have a model in my project called Context.  I have implemented a generic DetailView and an update page for the model using a modelform called ContextForm and a generic UpdateView called ContextUpdate.  Once the form is submitted, I redirect to the detail page using `get_absolute_url` in models.py:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("context:review",kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

My urlpatterns in urls.py looks something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$',views.ContextDetail.as_view(),name="review"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w]+)/edit$',views.ContextUpdate.as_view(),name="edit"),
]
```

I am able to access this parameter in my UpdateView quite easily:

```
def post(self,request,**kwargs):
        print (request.POST.get("bar")) #accessing input to form
        print (request.GET.get("bar")) #accesssing url parameter
        return super().post(request,**kwargs)
```

But when `get_absolute_url` is called inside the model, it seems I no longer have access to it.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?  I want to use get_absolute_url (along with modelforms, generic views, etc.) so that I can follow Django conventions, but it seems like using get_absolute_url is making the functionality that I want difficult to accomplish.  If the redirect to the detail view following the POST request were to happen inside my view, then I would know how to solve this (I think). Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you can't access the request inside your `get_absolute_url` method. Therefore you should override `get_success_url`, from which you can access it.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse(reverse("context:review", kwargs={"slug": self.object.slug}) + '?bar=%s' % self.request.GET.get('bar')
```

Or if you want to re-use `get_absolute_url`:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return self.object.get_absolute_url + '?bar=%s' % self.request.GET.get('bar')
```

The second option is DRYer but would break if `get_absolute_url` was changed to include a querystring like `?foo=foo`.